# How do I save header information, but remove the top row to iterate over (Pandas Dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

UPDATE: SOLVED ... thanks in advance!

I need to keep ahold of the column names in a data frame, but then I need to iterate over the rest of the rows. So I cannot do (headers=1) as a read_csv argument because I need the headers row information to save later. An issue I am having is I cannot drop the header row later on after saving the needed information. I have also tried iterating with a headers=None argument and include the headers row as an indexed row, but for some reason, it's then inserting a header row with a single 0 at the top and interferes with my ability to iterate over the data frame....

For example, part of my code, which is the approach that the header row as an index row breaks at split because it's inserting a zero at the top of the data frame...

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\n", header=None)
for row in data:
     row = row.split(",")
```

the data looks something like this. If I print the first row in the loop, it's the hanging zero?

```
                              0
0  Letter 1, Letter 2, Letter 3
1  A,B,C
```

UPDATE, SOLVED:

Thanks so much for the help! I solved it with this approach:

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\n" , header=None, skiprows=1)

        for row in data.iterrows():
            row = row[1].str.split(",").tolist()
```

Comment: can you post the format of your input file?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to mess with setting a separator as the newline character and then splitting the data again with ','. The default for read_csv is to do just that, so dont pass any other arguments!

```
data = pd.read_csv(file)
```

This will give you:

```
    Letter 1    Letter 2    Letter 3
0          A           B           C
```

I think what you are looking for is iterrows for **iterating** row by row.

```
for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

if you want the **header** without the data, then you can do

```
data.columns
```

if you want the **data as an array** without a header, then you can do

```
data.values
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response... The issue with this approach is that I need to split by comma per each row. Does .values change it to a numpy array, so I would have to change it to a string  to split it by comma and then back to a list?

Comment: read_csv splits by comma. csv stands for comma delimited values.

Comment: like i said, I would be really curious to see what your input file looks like in order to know why read_csv doesn't work

Comment: i know you said that you don't want to use read_csv in order to access the headers, but you can access the headers with data.columns

Comment: Hi Thanks so much for the comments, yeah it must be my input file. But I solved it, with this approach: data = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\n" , header=None, skiprows=1)

        for row in data.iterrows():
            row = row[1].str.split(",").tolist()